# What is "conditional" about conditional GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, conditional-probability, gan

I was recently reading the conditional GAN paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1784.pdf

In the conditional GAN paper, the author try to approximate two functions $D(x|y)$ and $G(z|y)$, where $x$ represents the image, $z$ represents noise, and $y$ represents on some additional information, for example, the class labels associated with image $x$.

My questions:

1. What makes conditional GAN conditional?
2. Is calling this GAN a conditional GAN really appropriate or even correct?
3. Why is it "conditional" GAN instead of "joint probability" GAN or GAN with some side information?

The first problem to me is that while $D$ has probabilistic interpretation, as it generates a value between $0$ and $1$, $G$ does not (it literally generates a vector in the MNIST example), $G$ is not a probability distribution, so how can we talk about $G$ as a condition probability distribution? The notation of $G(z|y)$ doesn't make sense.

Also, what does it mean by $D(x|y)$?
Recall that given two random variables $X, Y$, the conditional probability distribution $f_{Y|X}$ has the form,

$$
{\displaystyle f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)={\frac {f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}}}$$

Does $D(x|y)$ have a similar interpretation? I.e, suppose we computed $D(x|y)$, it is possible to recover $D(x,y)$ or $D(x)$? If not, how can we be sure that we learned $D(x|y)$?

Finally, from the implementation, it seems that $D(x|y)$ functions more as a $D(x, y)$ (a function of two arguments), as opposed to a function of a single argument $D(x|y)$. Also note that $y$ is not used here as a random variable, it is just a piece of information, i.e,. a vector. It does not make sense to condition on something that is not a random variable (does it?).

---

Can someone provide some insight as to whether calling it a conditional GAN make sense? Are we really computing conditional probabilities distributions here, or simply computing functions with more than 1 argument?

Conditioning to me as a precise mathematical meaning in probability (otherwise any function of multiple variables can be said to be "conditioning" on a subset of variables). Is there anything conditional about conditional GAN?

Comment: $D(x|y)$ mean "given that I want a specific class (or whatever information you want to be able to enforce) $y$, give me a possible $x$", so for example for mnist digits, that might be the digit class, for face generation, it can be the color of the hairs, and so on